# Will SharePoint let me know there are attachments on my saved email?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, email, outlook, attachments

When I save an email (with attachments) to SharePoint from Outlook, I would like to see an indicator that lets me know that there are attachments on the email.  I am aware that I can save the attachments separately.

What I am looking for is visual and very simple.  Is there a way to enable the paperclip icon in SharePoint to let me know there are attachments on the email I saved?

Comment: There is no out of the box solution that SharePoint set that type of flags. But you can achieve using Visual Studio Item Event Reciever solution. Is it the on-premises site? And is your organizations allows Visual Studio solutions? I will give you snippet that can be used in VS solition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override EmailReceived to know the attachment if any.

Below is the sample code that you can use in your event receiver. 
I have added two new columns in my list that will receive the email to know the total attachments and also the file names attached in the email.
TotalAttachments and AttachedFiles.

```
    SPEmailAttachmentCollection attachColl = emailMessage.Attachments;
    string AttachedFiles = string.Empty;
    int TotalAttachments = 0;
    foreach (SPEmailAttachment attach in attachColl)
    {
        AttachedFiles += attach.FileName + ";";
        TotalAttachments ++;
    }
```

Update the list with the columns "TotalAttachments" and "AttachedFiles"

```
    SPItem item = file.Item;
    item["TotalAttachments"] = TotalAttachments.ToString();
    item["AttachedFiles"] = AttachedFiles.ToString();
    item.Update();
    list.Update();
```